# While loop does not show table record values

Tags: php

I have two pieces of code.  The first code shows the value of a table column named 'title'. But the second piece of code with a while loop does not work. It is not showing the values of the table column named 'title'.

First Code:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cl_banner ORDER BY id";

    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
        {   
          $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)
          echo $row["title"];
        } // End If                     
?>
```

Second code :

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cl_banner ORDER BY id";

    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
        {   
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
            {   
                echo $row["title"]; 

            } // End While
        } // End If                     
?>
```

Comment: if command in the second file id unnecessary and you can remove that.

Comment: If the answer was useful for you, please mark it as accepted in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon from the end of the while.

And I can say that if command is completely unnecessary here and you can remove it without change.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cl_banner ORDER BY id";

    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
            {   
                echo $row["title"]; 

            } // End While               
?>
```